# What is the story of Mahishi?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, puranas, ayyappa

You may be familiar with God [Ayyappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyappan). He is also known as Manikanta. He is the main deity of [Sabarimala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabarimala) temple. He took the incarnation to kill the demon **Mahishi** who is the sister of Mahishasura. She wants to take revenge of her brother's death and makes penance for Brahma. She gets the boon from Brahma that she could be killed by a child born with fusion of two males. Ayyappan is born by the fusion of Mohini incarnation of Vishnu and Shiva. Later he kills Mahishi.

After thinking of this story, a few questions flashed in my mind. They are as follows:

- Where was the mention of this demon Mahishi in puranas?
- How many times did Mahavishnu take the avatara as Jaganmohini?
- In which yuga did the story of Ayyappa happen?

Comment: Ayyappa was born in the present Kali Yuga.  Contrary to popular belief, Ayyappa is technically not the son of Shiva and Mohini.  The son of Shiva and Mohini is named Dharma Shasta, and Ayyappa refers to prince Manikandan of Pandalam, who was a human incarnation of the god Dharma Shasta; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10134/36 The story of Ayyappa took place very recently; in fact Ayyappa had a Muslim friend named Vavar.