# Importance of Kleem bija mantra in Kali Kula and Vaishnava Sect

Tags: krishna, mantras, kali, sri-vidya, bijakshara

Any acharyas here, please elaborate the Importance of `Kleem` bija mantra in `Kali Kula` and `Vaishnava Sect`.
There are many Gopala mantras with "Kleem" beeja involved.

At the sametime, Bhadrakali moolamantra, ShmashanaKaali,Chamunda, BalaParameswari etc has also having this beeja mantra

Does this pointing to, Krishna and Kali are tightly linked with each other? or those Devataas whose beeja mantra has "Kleem" has a connection with Krishna?

Comment: I have seen somewhere that "la" (found in klim) and "ra" (or ref found in krim) are essentially the same which is validating the similarities you are referring to. But I coould not recollect now which book I read this in.

Comment: Ka -> Kam -> ananda.. -> bliss  lee- leena ->beholder or proprietor of Bliss  one who has bliss as his body is Kleem  that is krishna as told Bannaje Govindacharya in his lectures.. that is why its Kleem Krishnaya namaha.. is the mantra..

Comment: In many Tantra texts Kali is equated with Krishna. Check the answer to this question I had asked earlier: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/what-is-the-relation-between-dash-mahavidyas-and-dashavatar

Answer (score 5):

In the Tantrik scriptures and terminologies, Klim is widely known as the "kAma vija", which is associated primarily with Lord Krishna. On the other hand, Krim, known as the "sharmada vija", is associated exclusively with Goddess KAli. Krim is known as the KAli Vija and Klim the KAma Vija or Krishna Vija.

There is a Tantra, called the VaradA Tantram, which gives the expository meanings of the various Vijas (like aim, hrim, haum, shrim, dum, gam etc., etc.) in the Patala 6 of the text, by breaking down the letters, mAtrAs found in a particular Vija.

The verses I quote below are given in the book "Anhika Krityam - by Shyamacharana Sharma AKA Shyamacharana Kaviratnavaridhi", 1st bhAga, 1st khanda (on p.79):

### Klim

> Klim (KAma)--- Ka kAmdeva uddishtohapyathava krishna uchyate |
>  La Indra
> ee tushti-vAchi sukha-dukkah-pradancha ||
>
> ka --- kAmadeva or krishna; la --- Indra; symbolic here of opulence or
> Aisharya; ee --- Tushti or appeasement or pleasure; anuswara --- giver
> of happiness and destroyer of miseries.
>
> Over all meaning --- Let the opulent kAmadeva or Krishna provide me
> with pleasures and happiness and let him remove my miseries.

### Krim

> Krim (Sharmada) ---
>
> ka kAli brahma ra proktam mahA-mayArthakashcha eeh |
> viswa-mAtArthako nado vindur-dukkha-aharArthakah ||
>
> ka --- kAli; ra --- brahma (supreme reality); ee --- mahAmAyA (the
> great enchantress); nAdA --- viswa-mAtA (world mother); bindu ---
> dukkha harana (removal of miseries);
>
> Overall meaning --- Let, the mahAmAyA, Brahma-swarupa, Jagajjanani,
> Goddess KAli remove all my miseries.

Aspirants, who are initiated into KAli mantra, sip water during Achamana, using the mantra Krim. So, Krim is obviously important in KAli-Kula. Klim, on the other hand, is a generally important Vija, that is found in mantras of various deities, but is primarily associated with Krishna.

Comment: Looking through older posts and came across this, had been wondering the precise difference. Thx for the many helpful and informative comments/replies @Rickross

Comment: Thank you @devibhakt