# Is Krishna-Kali (a combined form of Krishna and Kali, worshipped in West Bengal) male or female?

Tags: krishna, gods, vedanta, dharma, kali

It is NOT like Ardhanarishvara, which shows the left-side being Shiva, and the right being Parvati. Instead, Krishna-Kali is just one form, resembling both Kali and Krishna, without any indication of any gender.

Comment: Hi, you may like to **link appropriate source and references to your question**, so everyone can know the extent and origin of your doubts.

Comment: I had always assumed it to be similar to Ardhanarishwar. BTW you may also want to check another one related to their unity that I had asked earlier: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/what-is-the-relation-between-dash-mahavidyas-and-dashavatar