# Narasimha is a form of Devi Durga?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, vaishnavism, devi, durga

In the Durga Chalisa, it says that:

> धरा रूप नरसिंह को अम्बा 
> प्रकट भई फाडकर खम्बा 
> रक्षा करि प्रह्लाद बचायो 
> हिरण्याक्ष को स्वर्ग पठायो 
> You Assumed the Form of Lord Narasimha,
> And Appeared Breaking the Pillar
> You Saved Prahlada 
> And Sent Hiranyakashyapu to Heaven (as he was killed by You)

Now I am aware of the sentiment that all deities, are in essence the same. I have also seen specific references in other scriptures, such as the one below given in the [Shivakamasundari Sahasranama Stotra]:

> ekaiva śaktiḥ parameśvarasya 
> bhinnā caturdhā viniyogakāle 
> bhoge bhavānī puruṣeṣu viṣṇuḥ 
> kopeṣu kālī samareṣu durgā

Which equates the form of goddess Bhavani with blessing devotees with all pleasures / desires, Vishnu as the masculine form of Devi, Kali as the manifestation of anger, and Durga as the manifestation on the battle field.

Are there are any specific sources that equate Devi Durga and Narasimha in any puranas?

Comment: There is one form of Durga which is also known as Narasimhi or the form of the Lion - Pratyangira https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyangira

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different texts, which equates 10 mahavidyas with 10 avatars differently. But, The MundamAla Tantram, which is a ShAkta Agama gives the list of Das Mahadyas and Das Avataras as follows:

> *Krishnastu kAlikA sAkshAd rAmamurtishcha tArini | VarAho bhuvanA proktA **nrisimho bhairavishwari** || DhumAvati vAmanah syachinna bhrigukulodbhavah | KamalA matsyarupah syAt kurmastu bagalAmukhi || MAtangi bauddha ityeshA shodashi kalkirupini |*

Here the mapping the relations is as follows:

> *KAli-- Krishna TArA-- RAma Bhuvaneswari-- VarAha **Bhairavi-- Nrisimha** DhumAvati-- VAmana Chinnamsta-- ParashurAma KamalA-- Matsya BagalAmukhi-- Kurma MAtangi-- Buddha Shodashi-- Kalki.*

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Comment: Good stuff. I thought it was Chinnmasta (I love her!) who was MahaVidya of Narsimh. Maybe that’s in a different text somewhere. Bhairavi is awesome too though ! Love all the MahaVidya so much :D

Comment: @devibhakt yes in todal tantra chapter 10 its maa chinna masta. *"Shri Shiva said: Tara Devi is the blue (fish) form, Bagala is the tortoise incarnation, Dhumavati is the boar, **Chinnamasta is Narisimha,** Bhuvaneshvari is Vamana, Matangi is the Rama form, Tripura is Jamadagni, Bhairavi is Balabhadra, Mahalakshmi is Buddha, and Durga is the Kalki form. BhagavatÌ Kali is the Krishna murti."* Jai Maa Shakti.

Comment: Thx for the info ! :) I’m slowly learning more and more about these things. Jay Maa Shakti :)

Comment: Good going. N u r welcome. ..

Answer (score 1):

Pratyangira Sanskrit: प्रत्यङ्गिरा, Pratyaṅgirā, also called Atharvana Bhadrakali, Narasimhi, Simhamukhi, and Nikumbala, is a Hindu goddess associated with Shaktism. She is described to be the female energy and consort( here consort means an analogy of Narasimha). According to the Tripura Rahasya, she is the pure manifestation of the wrath of Tripura Sundari. In the Vedas, Pratyangira is represented in the form of Atharvana Bhadrakali, the goddess of the Atharva Veda and magical spells. Narasimhi is part of the Saptamatrika mother goddesses. Similarly Varaha in the dasavatar is associated with Varahi

Similar question - [What is the relation between Dash Mahavidyas and Dashavatar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/what-is-the-relation-between-dash-mahavidyas-and-dashavatar)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratyangira

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavidya#:~:text=The%2010%20Mahavidyas%20are%20usually,%2C%20Bagalamukhi%2C%20Matangi%20and%20Kamala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavidya#:%7E:text=The%2010%20Mahavidyas%20are%20usually,%2C%20Bagalamukhi%2C%20Matangi%20and%20Kamala).

This is a completely logical analogy, As mentioned in the vedas Uma is Vishnu and Vishnu is Uma himself :)